# TensorFlow fit using dataset from generator with multiple outputs: Cannot properly define shapes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am attempting to convert a project to a single network with multiple outputs using a generator but I cannot seem to work out how to get the multiple outputs to function properly when a generator is being used.  Here is a minimally verifiable hunk of code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

def generate_sample():
    x = list("123456789")
    y = list("2345")
    while 1:
        yield np.array(x).astype(np.float32),[np.array(y).astype(np.float32),np.array(y).astype(np.float32)]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generate_sample,
            output_signature=(
                 tf.TensorSpec(shape=(9,), dtype=tf.float32),
                 tf.TensorSpec(shape=(2,4), dtype=tf.float32)

            ))

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=32)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(next(generate_sample())[0].shape))
x = layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu")(inputs)
x_outputs = layers.Dense(4, activation="relu", name="output")(x)
y_outputs = layers.Dense(4, activation="relu", name="output2")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[x_outputs,y_outputs])
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer = "adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=10, validation_data=dataset, validation_steps=5)
```

This results in a very long error, the final portion of which is:

> InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,2,4] vs. [32,4]
> [[node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference (defined at
> :1) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_8957]
>
> Function call stack: train_function

I have tried this using `output_shape`, `output_signature`, etc. with every way I can imagine reshaping the data.  No matter what, I continue to run into shape problems.

Am I missing something obvious here or is there something wrong in `fit` using a generator as a source for a dataset?  I have no problem doing this when I'm loading the data from memory, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of the model is not one Tensor of shape `(2,4)`, but two Tensors of shape `(4)`.

You should change your generator function to reflect that:

```
def generate_sample():
    x = list("123456789")
    y = list("2345")
    while 1:
        yield np.array(x).astype(np.float32),(np.array(y).astype(np.float32),np.array(y).astype(np.float32))
```

As well as your output signature:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generate_sample,
            output_signature=(
                 tf.TensorSpec(shape=(9,), dtype=tf.float32),
                 (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(4,), dtype=tf.float32),
                 tf.TensorSpec(shape=(4,), dtype=tf.float32)),
            ))
```

Note that the output of the generator is a nested tuple.

Comment: That sounds nice but also fails.

Comment: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was (tf.float32, (tf.float32, tf.float32)), but the yielded element was (array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.], dtype=float32), [array([2., 3., 4., 5.], dtype=float32), array([2., 3., 4., 5.], dtype=float32)]).

Comment: Let me try to change the yield to be a nested tuple

Comment: OH MY GOD... Could it really be that easy?  Thank you.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I understand that 'useless' comments are frown upon, but my jaw just dropped when I saw a nested tuple was the fix. Dio mio.